# Couldn't fetch MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm trying to re-code a homepage I made. This time I want to use OOP style, but I always get following error:

> Statistic::checkExistingCounter() [statistic.checkexistingcounter]: Couldn't fetch MySQL

What am I doing wrong? I know that the prepare statement is senseless, but even just a query instead of prepare statement is not working at all.

Same error:

> Couldn't fetch MySQL

My Database class:

```
class MySQL extends MySQLi {

    private static $_instance = null;
    private $host, $username, $password, $db;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!(self::$_instance instanceof self)) {
            self::$_instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function __construct(){
        $this->host = '...';
        $this->username = '...';
        $this->password = '...';
        $this->database = '...';
        $this->connect();
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        $this->db->close();
    }

    private function __clone(){} 

    public function connect() {
        $this->db = @new MySQLi($this->host, $this->username, $this->password, $this->database);

        /* change character set to utf8 */
        $this->db->set_charset("utf8");

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        return $this->db;
    }
}
```

My statistic class:

```
 class Statistic {
    private $remote, $user_agent, $referer; 
    private $db;

    /**
     * Create Instance of MySQL
     **/
    function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = MySQL::getInstance();
    }

    /**
     * Check for counter today
     *
     * @param: string SQL
     * @return: boolean (true = Counter exists, false = Counter doesnt exist)
     **/
    function checkExistingCounter($sql) {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);

        $this->db->error;

        if (!$stmt) {
            echo 'Datenbankfehler';
            exit;
        }

        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();

        if ($stmt->num_rows) {
            $stmt->close();
            return true;
        } else {
            $stmt->close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    function counter() {
        $sql = "SELECT ID FROM Counter WHERE Datum = CURDATE()";
        $checkCounter = $this->checkExistingCounter($sql);
    }
```

And this is a part of my index.php:

```
$db = new MySQL();
$statistic = new Statistic($db);
$statistic->counter();
```

Comment: What does `MySQL::getInstance` do?

Comment: @ExplosionPills It looks very much like the Singleton Pattern to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be in a muddle here, implementing two sets of competing coding patterns:

- your `MySQL` class both extends `MySQLi` (that is, any `MySQL` object is also a `MySQLi` object) and "delegates" to a `MySQLi` instance in its private variable `$db`
- your `Statistic` class takes an instance of `MySQL` in its constructor ("dependency injection"), but then ignores it and asks the `MySQL` class for a "singleton" instance.

You need to read up more carefully on what each of these patterns is for, and decide on one or the other in each case (inheritance **or** delegation, dependency injection **or** singletons).

Currently, your code will do the following:

1. create a new `MySQL` object (which is also a `MySQLi` object, but hasn't been initialised to any particular database connection, because you haven't called `parent::__construct()`)
2. in the `MySQL` constructor, set `$this->host` etc
3. in the `connect()` method, create a new `MySQLi` object, passing it the host etc
4. save this object as `$this->db`, which is only ever referenced in the destructor (`$this->db->close()`)
5. return the `MySQLi` object from `connect()`, but nothing in `__construct()` is looking at that return value
6. back in the outer code, the `MySQL` object is passed to the constructor of the `Statistic` class
7. the constructor then ignores this, and calls the Singleton method `MySQL::getInstance()` instead
8. the `getInstance()` method (since this is the first time it has been called) will create a second `MySQL` object, repeating steps 1 to 5
9. this second `MySQL` object will be saved as `$this->db` on the `Statistics` object
10. the `checkExistingCounter` method attempts to use `$this->db` as a `MySQLi` connection, but the `MySQL` object was never connected to any database, so you get an error. (There is a connected connection, and if it wasn't private, you could access it as `$this->db->db`. There's another one kicking around as well, which was created at step 2, but you can't access that any more, because you ignored it at step 7.)